# Tabulator in Javascript - Buggy column moving

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator to display some data in my js app. When I move columns around (using movableColumns: true), it works normally. When I add a new column programmatically and then try to move that column around, it displays this behavior:

[image: Errored Image]

Any Tabulator experts know what could be going on?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your tabulator options and column setup?  I am not able to duplicate this with a basic setup on my end.  Something with your configuration maybe causing this.

Comment: Could you prepare snipped with this?